# Do not rerender an HOC component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, with different routes.

Some routes require a Menu type A and other a menu type B.

I create 2 HOC component that create the 2 different menu, and each of my route will call a component that use the HOC.

for exemple :

```
<PrivateRoute path="/ws/:ws/pj/:pj/rp/:rp" component={HomeReport} />
<PrivateRoute path="/ws/:ws/pj/:pj/ds/:ds" component={HomeDatastore} />
```

HomeReport looks like this

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withTranslation()(withMenuA(HomeReport)));

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withTranslation()(withMenuA(HomeDatastore)));
```

Now, this looks nice, the problem is, when I change component that use the same menu (HomeReport => HomeDatastore)

All the Left menu is completely redraw, since it's inside a new component.

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent my HOC component to be redrawn at every component change.

Comment: I would try to hoist your HOC to some sort of react context provider at the top of your app (or similar) and pass methods of the menu (e.g. reveal hide) via context to your components that use them. Can you include some mockups of how your menu component looks visually? might be able to give a more concrete answer

Comment: a very quick mockup is this https://prnt.sc/s0wx04

Basicaslly, when i am navigating inside of those 4 element, I have menu A, else is menu B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your design, your menus are in drawers and drawers are components that can be safely hoisted to the top of your app (because they aren't inline another component).

If you hoist the drawer, it will no longer re-render based on the route you're on simply because they're not part of that component's tree anymore.

Since you're already using Redux for global state, I would suggest:

- creating a drawer component that exists at the top level of your app
- passing methods down to manipulate the drawer state (e.g. open closed etc) via react context (or via redux, either is fine)

[Here's a CodeSandbox demonstrating the idea.](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-meadow-0e013?file=/src/Drawer.js) This one uses react context with examples of react hooks and HOCs.

Note: you can also further wrap that drawer component in any HOC you want to (e.g. redux).

Comment: Yes I am currently changing like this. 

The only downside I have with this solution, is that every component need to manually set the drawer state or it can lead to bug where it appear/not appear where it should(nt)

Comment: If you're using hooks, you can include an effect in the `useDrawer` hook (referencing my codesandbox) that will reset the state on mount. If you're not using hooks, can you use use componentDidMount inside the returning component to run that side effect

Comment: What I mean is more like, every time a component with menu A appear, it has to show and hide the proper menu using context or redux. Same with component using menu B. Or it might lead to 2 menu or incorrect menu displayed on the displayed component. My drawer is listening to a redux state, so every main component need to toggle that state.
But I guess there is no better solution. Thanks :)